# How to self join on date calculation and other fields in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Got a query that gets bookings data grouped by date, operator, source, route and I want to self join it so that I have the same data against it but joined on the previous year's date (add 1 day to align the weekday).

For example, if we had

```
date      |num|
----------|---|
2017-01-01|300|
2017-01-02|301|
2017-01-03|302|
2017-01-04|303|
2017-01-05|304|
2017-01-06|305|
2017-01-07|306|
2017-01-08|307|
2017-01-09|308|
2017-01-10|309|
...
2018-01-01|501|
2018-01-02|502|
2018-01-03|503|
2018-01-04|504|
2018-01-05|505|
2018-01-06|506|
2018-01-07|507|
2018-01-08|508|
2018-01-09|509|
2018-01-10|510|
...
```

Then I would want result to be

```
date      |num| date      |num|
----------|---| ----------|---|
2017-01-01|300| null      |null|
2017-01-02|301| null      |null|
2017-01-03|302| null      |null|
2017-01-04|303| null      |null|
2017-01-05|304| null      |null|
2017-01-06|305| null      |null|
2017-01-07|306| null      |null|
2017-01-08|307| null      |null|
2017-01-09|308| null      |null|
2017-01-10|309| null      |null|
...
2018-01-01|501| 2017-01-02|301|
2018-01-02|502| 2017-01-03|302|
2018-01-03|503| 2017-01-04|303|
2018-01-04|504| 2017-01-05|304|
2018-01-05|505| 2017-01-06|305|
2018-01-06|506| 2017-01-07|306|
2018-01-07|507| 2017-01-08|307|
2018-01-08|508| 2017-01-09|308|
2018-01-09|509| 2017-01-10|309|
2018-01-10|510| 2017-01-11|...|
```

What I've got so far

```
select

a.date          as date1
,a.source       as source1
,a.operator     as operator1
,a.route        as route1
,a.sum          as bookings1

,b.date         as date2
,b.source       as source2
,b.operator     as operator2
,b.route        as route2
,b.sum          as bookings2

from

(select 
date
,source
,operator
,route
,sum(record_count)
from booking
where transaction_date >= dateadd(year, -2, current_date)
group by 1,2,3,4) a

full outer join

(select 
date
,source
,operator
,route
,sum(record_count)
from booking
where date between dateadd(year, -3, current_date) and dateadd(year, -1, current_date)
group by 1,2,3,4) b

on

b.date                          = dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(year, -1, a.date))
and a.source                    = b.source
and a.outbound_operator_name    = b.outbound_operator_name
and a.outbound_route_name       = b.outbound_route_name

;
```

The problem with the above query is that it show's the correct 2018 results but not the correct 2017 results. I presume there's something wrong with either the join type or something within the on clause e.g. the date calculation attempt...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the results? And why would the sub-query "a" have a criteria on "transaction_date" but "b" on "date"?

Comment: I aggregate the results in Excel or Tableau for each day and 2018 show numbers show correctly but 2017 always is less than what it should be. The reason for the criteria is so that I can match the same day against previous year (with an added extra day so that we're matching on the same weekday e.g. Monday vs Monday).

Comment: Issue I've got is that if there's a missing bookings count in subquery 'b' for a given date, operator and route then it doesn't join onto subquery 'a', thus showing less results in subquery 'b'. I would have thought that the full outer join would've compensated for this? Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @LukStorms it should both be 'date' and not 'transaction_date'

Comment: With a FULL JOIN it would show all of "a" and all of "b".  Linking them where there's a match. So if you say there are "missing", then they are already not in the resultsets of "a" or "b".  Maybe you think they are missing because you select based on the current date, and not on the current month?  And also, normally it's better to join on an id instead of a name, because names could have different spelling or typos.

Comment: Interesting, if the intention is to join on the same weekday, then with that day+1 that would only work with comparing specific years.  To make that work for any current date, this might become more complicated. Like joining on the same week number & day of the week?

Comment: Thanks for the responses @LukStorms - I'm still confused as to why my subquery b's results are less than what it should be...it feels as though the result is like that of a left join rather than a full join because like you said, the full join should bring back all of 'a' and all of 'b'

Comment: The problem with questions regarding Amazon-redshift is that for the people that want to answer it then there doesn't seem to be a free online tester like rextester.com of db-fiddle for it.  But [HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=754ae2c8e47655fe59979b4d39d57517) is a db-fiddle for a Postgres 8.4 (which should be close enough I guess).  I think that if you look at the date criteria, and the results then with a full join all are there.